# keras: unsupervised learning with external constraint

Tags: keras, constraints, loss-function, unsupervised-learning

I have to train a network on unlabelled data of binary type (True/False), which sounds like unsupervised learning. This is what the normalised data look like:

```
array([[-0.05744527, -1.03575495, -0.1940105 , -1.15348956, -0.62664491,
    -0.98484037],
   [-0.05497629, -0.50935675, -0.19396862, -0.68990988, -0.10551919,
    -0.72375012],
   [-0.03275552,  0.31480204, -0.1834951 ,  0.23724946,  0.15504367,
     0.29810553],
   ...,
   [-0.05744527, -0.68482282, -0.1940105 , -0.87534175, -0.23580062,
    -0.98484037],
   [-0.05744527, -1.50366446, -0.1940105 , -1.52435329, -1.14777063,
    -0.98484037],
   [-0.05744527, -1.26970971, -0.1940105 , -1.33892142, -0.88720777,
    -0.98484037]])
```

However, I do have a *constraint on the total number of True* labels in my data. This doesn't mean I can build a classical custom loss function in Keras taking `(y_true, y_pred)` arguments as required: my external constraint is just on the predicted total of `True` and `False`, not on the individual labels.

My question is whether there is a somewhat "standard" approach to this kind of problems, and how that is implementable in Keras.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Should I assign `y_true` randomly as 0/1, have a network return `y_pred` as 1/0 with a sigmoid activation function, and then define my loss function as

```
sum_y_true = 500 # arbitrary constant known a priori

def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = np.abs(y_pred.sum() - sum_y_true)
    return loss
```

Comment: As per my understanding, you need to constraint the number of True and number of False label. am I right?

Comment: Exactly. It's basically like a k-means clustering problem, in which I have the advantage of knowing that

a) k = 2;

b) how many datapoints need to end up in each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with the following solution, which worked.

1) Define batches in your dataframe `df` with a `batch_id` column, so that in each batch `Y_train` is your *identical* "batch ground truth" (in my case, the total number of True labels in the batch). You can then pass these instances together to the network. This can be done with a generator:

```
def grouper(g,x,y):
    while True:
        for gr in g.unique():
            # this assigns indices to the entire set of values in g,
            # then subsects to all the rows in which g == gr
            indices = g == gr
            yield (x[indices],y[indices])

# train set
train_generator = grouper(df.loc[df['set'] == 'train','batch_id'], X_train, Y_train)
# validation set
val_generator = grouper(df.loc[df['set'] == 'val','batch_id'], X_val, Y_val)
```

2) define a custom loss function, to track how close the *total number* of instances predicted as true matches the ground truth:

```
def custom_delta(y_true, y_pred):

loss = K.abs(K.mean(y_true) - K.sum(y_pred))

return loss


def custom_wrapper():

    def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
        return custom_delta(y_true, y_pred)

    return custom_loss_function
```

Note that here

a) Each `y_true` label is *already* the sum of the ground truth in our batch (cause we don't have individual values). That's why `y_true` is not summed over;

b) `K.mean` is actually a bit of an overkill to extract a single scalar from this uniform tensor, in which all y_true values in each batch are identical - `K.min` or `K.max` would also work, but I haven't tested whether their performance is faster.

3) Use `fit_generator` instead of `fit`:

```
fmodel = Sequential()
# ...your layers...
# Create the loss function object using the wrapper function above
loss_ = custom_wrapper()
fmodel.compile(loss=loss_, optimizer='adam')

history1 = fmodel.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=total_batches, 
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=df.loc[encs.df['set'] == 'val','batch_id'].nunique(),
    epochs=20, verbose = 2)
```

This way the problem is basically addressed as one of supervised learning, although without individual labels, which means that notions like true/false positive are meaningless here.

This approach not only managed to give me a `y_pred` that closely matches the totals I know per batch. It actually finds two groups (True/False) that occupy the expected different portions of parameter space.